# The function for comparing arrays with null object does not work

Tags: javascript

There is a function, it compares 2 arrays for a match, if they match: true, otherwise: false

But the conditions say that the array can have a null object and if it is present in the array, you need to output false. But I cannot understand why my code does not work, I tried to write in different ways, but the output is the same, no matter whether there is null in the array or not

```js
var isSameTree = function(p, q) {
    for(let i = 0; i <= p.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j <= q.length; j++) {
            if(p[i] || q[j] == null) {
                return false
            }
                if(p[i] == q[j]) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false   
            }
        }
    }
};
console.log(isSameTree([1,null,2], [1,2]));
```

```
Your input
[1,2,3],[1,2,3]

Output
false

Expected
true
```

Answer (score 2):

This condition:

```
if(p[i] || q[j] == null) {
```

Looks like it should be:

```
if(p[i] === null || q[j] === null) {
```

Also, you'll need to count indexes separately from those that iterate over your arrays. So in your first example, `i` should not increase if `null` is seen.

Finally, you're using a `<=` comparison operator against the array-lengths, where I believe you'll need `<` instead.

Comment: Now it simply displays true, even if null is in the array, I forgot to mention that if you put null at the very beginning, and not in the middle or end, then the function will work

Comment: Perhaps an easier approach would be to sanitize the arrays first. Remove the nulls, then perform the comparison.